# Adding fade animation to my ready Slideshow

Tags: javascript, css, animation, slideshow, fade

what im trying to do is to make my slideshow do some animation while changing photos, i have the very basic slide show

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
<div class="slider-wrapper-item " style="background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/ETL/img/slider-image-1.jpg);"></div>
<div class="slider-wrapper-item" style="background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/ETL/img/slider-image-2.jpg);"></div>
<div class="slider-wrapper-item" style="background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/ETL/img/slider-image-3.jpg);"></div>
<div class="slider-wrapper-item" style="background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/ETL/img/slider-image-4.jpg);"></div>
<div class="slider-wrapper-item" style="background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/ETL/img/slider-image-5.jpg);"></div>
<div class="slider-play-icon"><img src="/wp-content/themes/ETL/img/play-arrow-grey.png"></div>
```

this is the js

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-wrapper-item");
  console.log("slides",slides);
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
```

i have found an article on how to make the fade animation but its complicated and i have no luck with it https://cobwwweb.com/simple-looping-crossfade-image-slideshow
this is the exact animation i want.

Comment: And what is your problem ?

Comment: i have tried to do it myself for 2 days without luck, i broke some of my website but lucky i had a backup.. i need someone to give me a hand on what to do and how it works @Dokksen

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want animation you can't use display none or block because display property does not support transition.
don't use this 
slides[i].style.display = "none" and slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
instead of that make class for animation and add that class and remove whenever you want.

for example
 
.addAnimation{
 // write your code here
}
.removeAnimation{
 // write your code here
}
```

Comment: can you help me with the right class, from what i understand it has inside some advanced css, my understanding in css is very basic, i know to set opacity to 1 but not to animate it